# React Hooks, declare same state for different vars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If I have:

```
function ExampleWithManyStates() {

    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    ...
    const [price, setPrince] = useState(0);
```

Is there a way to set `useState(0)` to all `age, count, price`?

edit: example (I'm trying to explain me, I'm not saying that array destructuring should work like this)

```
    const [ {age, count, price}, {setAge, setCount, setPrice}] = useState(0);
```

A one line manner?

Comment: Are you asking if  you can update them all at once?

Comment: Not update but declare the initial state `0` for each state

Comment: It looks like that is already what you are doing...

Comment: Hooks work by knowing the order in which they are called on each render. You need to call `useState` three times in order to have three different state values.

Comment: No. You just have to do what you're doing.

Comment: I will put an example, invented syntax

Comment: @BrianThompson ah, well, ok, thanks.

Comment: One option might be [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) - this would allow you to declare an object with the keys `age`, `count`, `price` etc. and then set them based on separate actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compose your own hook if you wanted to tidy this up or reuse it:

```
const useStates = (count, initialValue) => {
  const states = []
  for (let i=0; i<count; i++) {
    states.push(useState(initialValue))
  }
  return states
}

const ExampleWithManyStates = () => {
  const [[age, setAge], [count, setCount], [price, setPrice]] = useStates(3, 0)
}
```

Not sure this is a great pattern for most use cases, but I don't really know what you're trying to do.

Comment: It works, but kind of goes against the first [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Spiritually yes, but you can absolutely [shirk these guidelines and stay out of trouble](https://inventingwithmonster.io/20190207-break-the-rules-of-react-hooks/) if you understand why the guidelines are there and what's happening underneath the hood.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it works, but I would absolutely not advocate this pattern! One reason is it could fail as soon as someone thinks they can initialize this with a prop, like `useStates(props.stateCount, 0)`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Nor am I advocating for this approach, merely providing it as a possible solution or educational opportunity. For what it's worth, your example would fail with a pretty clear error about the number of hooks being different than on the last render. Not sure why you feel it necessary to opine on the matter in any case, particularly as I've already called out the dubiousness.

Comment: We agree that it's not a great pattern, I'm not arguing, merely sharing to anyone that rules of hooks exists for a reason. Have a nice day anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was downvote but I learnt a lot by reading the comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an initial state, and then apply it to each:

```
function ExampleWithManyStates() {

    const initialState = 0;

    const [age, setAge] = useState(initialState);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(initialState);
    ...
    const [price, setPrince] = useState(initialState);
```

But I'm not sure there is any immediate benefit to doing so - the downside would be a lack of clarity looking at each item what the state would be without referring to the initial state variable.